# produce several maps in same figure window in matlab

Tags: matlab, mapping

I would like to generate a figure in matlab which looks like the attached .jpeg:

[image]

So, the figure should contain an outline of the world and then 3 other figures looking at the USA, UK, and New Zealand where I can then specify individual locations in each country. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subplots to arrange things, images to create the maps, and lines to connect them to points.  To create a complicated subplot structure like that I'd suggest you check out Ben Mitch's [panel](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20003) class.  The relevant thing you're looking for is its ability to conveniently divide up and manage subplots.  Something like this

```
p = panel('defer');
p.pack('v', [1/5 3/5 1/5]);
p(1).pack('h',[1/5 2/5 2/5]);  % top level, US and New Zealand
p(2).pack('h',[1/5 2/5 2/5]);  % mid level
p(3).pack('h',[1/5 3/5 1/5]);  % bottom level

p(2,2).select();
image(world_image);
p(1,3).select();
image(new_zealand_image);
p(1,3).select();
image(usa_image);
p(1,1).select();
image(uk_iamge);
```

Then add a few [line](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/line.html) commands to show where the submaps link to.  Note that I haven't gotten a chance to test the above code yet, but will when I get to work.  I can't remember offhand if it likes the 'h' argument within the child panels.